# Navigating to another view iPhone sdk?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible for me to navigate to a view that has uitextfield and make it so that uitextfield doesn't change everytime I navigate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a text that was previously, there...

there is a lot of options but an easy an fast one is have a static NSString....

so in your class you have the uitextfield, in that class you define 
static NSString *myString;

then, when the user or you modify it and you have access to it, define it in the static NSString.

Now, to recover it, in the method you initialize that view you do:

myTextField.text = myString;

that, will restore the text.

Comment: I am pretty sure there would be another way to do it am I right?

Comment: Hi, I want to make something like now playing button in iPod application on the iPhone